# rails association has many with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :hospitals
 has_many :employees
end 


class Hospital < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :city
 has_many :employees
end


class Employee < ApplicationRecord     
  belongs_to :hospital
  belongs_to :city
end
```

These are my models. Is there any way to get employees for hospital where the hospital located without passing `@city` parameter in `Hospital` model.

```
hospital.rb

has_many :employees, ->(hospital_city) { where(city: hospital_city) }
```

This works fine. but I need to pass the hospital_city everytime. I want something like this.

```
has_many :employees, -> { #do something and return employees belongs to hospital & hospital city.  }
```

`through` not works since employee table has `city_id`, `hospital_id`

Comment: Why do you think you actually need two foreign keys on your employees table instead of just using indirect associations? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 1):

You could just define a method on Hospital.

```
class Hospital < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :employees

  def employees_in_city
    employees.where(city: city)
  end
end
```